# How to log without crash in Android?

Tags: android, logging, error-handling, crashlytics, google-fabric

I have integrated Fabric for crash capturing. But in a special case, I need to just log some details on the fabric. But I didn't find any way to add a log without a crash. Each time I need to crash app to see logs.

```
Crashlytics.log(subStr);    
Crashlytics.logException(new RuntimeException("Exception"));
```

If I just add logs, I didn't see logs on Fabric. I need to explicitly throw an exception.

I am looking for a way where I can just log detail? I don't want crash logs.

Comment: can you try your code using "try" and "catch" block ? put your log into try-catch block

Comment: @Niceumang How it could help?

Answer (score 1):

Fabric crashlytics doesn't capture "non-exceptions".

Only when an exception is called will it appear in your console, whether that be fatal or non-fatal.

---

If you want to log events, any events you want, you can use [Answers](https://fabric.io/kits/android/answers) for that.

To use Answers, you will first have to implement  it like this:

In your app level gradle:

```
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.7@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
```

In your Manifest (I assume this will already be there since you're already using Crashlytics):

```
<meta-data
    android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey"
    android:value="3323d86155070b69e4558c773e7bdb6dc495cd9f"
/>
```

Then in your MainActivity or your Application class, you should initialize Answers, like this:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Answers());
```

Whenever you want to log something you can call it like this example:

```
Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent("Video Played")
        .putCustomAttribute("Category", "Comedy")
        .putCustomAttribute("Length", 350));
```

The log will then be displayed in your Fabrics console.

---

It's also important to note that you will soon have to move to Google Crashlytics, as [Fabric is closing.](https://get.fabric.io/roadmap?utm_campaign=discover&utm_medium=natural)

Answer (score 0):

```
Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(new RuntimeException("Exception"));
```

Try this. I got Log in Fabric without crash

Comment: I want to log without throwing new RuntimeException("Exception").

Comment: I just want to add log with no exception as simple as that.

Comment: Crashlytics in fabric no give direct Log function